# Converting $http.get to Restangular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest, restangular

Alrighty, for an internship project I am trying to create a simple client for a REST API. The current client is using regular angularJS, but I need to use Restangular for this.

I have been searching around a lot, trying out a lot of things, but nothing quite helped me do what I want, or understand what needs to happen.

This is the code snippet that needs to turn into Restangular

```
$http.get('/rest/programarticle/', {
  'format': 'json'
}).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
  $scope.articles = angular.articles = data.results;
});
```

This picks up JSON data which contains some meta data, aswell as an array (results):

```
{
    "count": 3,
    "next": null,
    "previous": null,
    "results": [
        {
            "id": 100,
            "catalog": 7,
            "catalog_alias": "placeHolder",
            "program": 7,
            "name": "placeHolder"
        },
        {
            "id": 92,
            "catalog": 6,
            "catalog_alias": "placeHolder",
            "program": 6,
            "name": "placeHolder"
        },
        {
            "id": 84,
            "catalog": 5,
            "catalog_alias": "string",
            "program": 5,
            "name": "placeHolder"
        }
    ]
}
```

I have my baseUrl configured correctly, and I tried this out:

```
var testArticles = Restangular.all('programarticle').getList();
console.log(testArticles);
```

Using the following ResponseInterceptor:

```
RestangularProvider.addResponseInterceptor(function(data, operation, what, url, response, deferred) {
    var extractedData;
    if (operation === "getList") {
        extractedData = data.results;
        extractedData.count = data.count;
        extractedData.next = data.next;
        extractedData.previous = data.previous;
    } else {
        extractedData = data.data;
    }
    return extractedData;
});
```

But this still results in something I can't work with in the console:

```
Promise {$$state: Object, restangularCollection: true, $object: Array[0]}
```

Which when opened shows the following:

```
$$state: Object
$object: Array[7]
call: wrapper()
get: wrapper()
push: wrapper()
restangularCollection: true
__proto__: Promise
```

It does show an array($object), but I cannot reach it using

```
console.log(testArticles.$object);
```

Should I be using .get() instead of getList()? If so, how do I use this correctly?

Thank you for your time and please suggest, I am still a beginner.

Comment: Have you configured Restangular to add the `/rest` base to the API calls?
Why is the data returned from the interceptor not something you can work with? What data are you seeing instead of the expected data?

Comment: @EzequielMuns  Yes I have the base url configured, I will edit my post shortly so it contains the things you just called :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What the `get`/`getList` functions from restangular return are actually Promises, not the JSON objects retrieved themselves. Promises are a way of abstracting an asynchronous call with a more manageable interface. They stand for an expected future result.

What you need to know is that to get the actual result of the Promise, you must add a callback using the `then` function, like so:

```
Restangular.all('programarticle').getList().then(function (articles) {
    $scope.articles = articles;
});
```

Read more about promises [here](http://www.dwmkerr.com/promises-in-angularjs-the-definitive-guide/).

Comment: Thanks! This already returns something more useful to the console. I had a read on the article, but as the scrub I am I stil don't exactly know how to **use** this promise and the data in it. Could I ng-repeat for article in articles now? Or do I need something else?

Comment: Should be able to `ng-repeat` on the returned articles array.

Comment: Thank you dearly good sir! I should now be able to finally get going.